# Howto see if form fields are identical in Zend framework

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework

In Zend Framework (1.10) i want to check if two input fields are identical
I have the following code in my form:

```
$this->addElement('password', 'password', array(
        'label'      => 'Wachtwoord:',
        'required'   => true
    )
);

$this->addElement('password', 'verifypassword', array(
        'label'      => 'Bevestig wachtwoord:',
        'required'   => true,
    )
);
```

I already tryed the "identical" validator, but I did'nt got it to work.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347856/zend-form-how-to-check-2-fields-are-identical

Comment: the Identical Validator should works well, what is your problem with ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom validation filter to accomplish this.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html

The documentation outlines what you are describing, under Note: Validation Operates On Filtered Values with a class called My_Validate_PasswordConfirmation