# Using Zend_Validate_Identical in Form Validation

Tags: php, zend-framework, validation

I'm trying to use the 'Identical' validator to validate whether two passwords are the same in my registration form, but it keeps trying to validate against the actual word I enter for the token rather than the form element that I want to validate against. Code looks like this: (This is my form model constructor..)

```
    $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');
    $password->addValidator('Regex',false,array('pattern' => '/^.*(?=.{6,20})(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])/'))
             ->addValidator('StringLength',false,array('max'=>20))
             ->setRequired(true);

    $password2 = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password2');
    $password2->setRequired(true);
    $password2->addValidator('Identical',false,array('token'=>'password'));       
    $register = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('register');

    $this->setDecorators(array(
                                array('ViewScript', 
                                       array('viewScript' => '_form_registration.phtml'))  
                              )     
                        );

    $this->addElements(array($firstName,$lastName,$email,$city,$password,$password2,$register));
```

Instead of validating against the form element called 'password' it keeps trying to match against the actual string 'password'

The work around I have is that I create a validator after the data has been posted to the controller, and validate against the post data, but if there is any more modular way to do this (AKA leaving the logic within the form constructor) I would love to know.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347856/zend-form-how-to-check-2-fields-are-identical

Comment: This example doesn't work for me. I'm trying to place the validator within the form model, but it keeps trying to compare against the "actual string" rather than the linked token..What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: iirc the only way i could get past this was creating the validator in the controller, after you check to see if isPost() is true. that way you can set the token to the value of the first password

Comment: This is weird since i use the same code almost and it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you outputting your form correctly?

I see that the decorator you're using is ViewScript so I'm guessing that you are coding the form's html yourself in some other script.

If so, are you following the Zend way of assigning names and id values to your elements? If you aren't, when you pass in the values to your form the context might not be set up correctly and it won't find the 'password' element that you need to check against.

My suggestion right now is to ouput the form using the form default decorators and look at how the ids and names look for the elements. Then, try to copy those names in the form.phtml that you're using.

Comment: That might work. I'll check and get back later..thx for the tip

Comment: Any luck comparing your output with that of zend's?

Answer (score 1):

After add the Identical Validator on your 'password2' element.

Try to overload isValid() function into your Form Object like this:

```
    public function isValid ($data)
    {
        $this->getElement('password2')    
             ->getValidator('Identical')
             ->setToken($data['password'])
             ->setMessage('Passwords don\'t match.');
        return parent::isValid($data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the exact same issue.
It was fixed by rewriting the code with an outside function to validate identical as such.

```
<?php
class RegisterForm extends Zend_Form
{
    /**
     * create your form
     */
    public function init()
    {
        $this->addElements(array(
            new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password',
                array( 'label' => 'Password:',
                           'required' => true,
                           'filters' => array('StringTrim', 'StripTags'),
                           'validators' => array(array(StringLength', false, array(5, 25)))
                )
            ),
            new Zend_Form_Element_Password('pass_twice',
                array('label' => 'Pass Twice',
                         'required' => true,
                         'filters' => array('StringTrim', 'StripTags'),
                         'validators' => array('Identical')
                )
            )
        );
    }

    public function isValid($data)
    {
        $passTwice = $this->getElement('pass_twice');
        $passTwice->getValidator('Identical')->setToken($data['password']);
        return parent::isValid($data);
    }
}
?>
```

Solution from: http://emanaton.com/node/38